# Simulink Mask initialization command and RuntimeObject

Tags: matlab, simulink

Here is code for my mask initialization I want to use it to change the color according to outputs of one of the blocks

```
systems = find_system(gcb,'LookUnderMasks' , 'on', 'FollowLinks','on', 'SearchDepth', 1,'regexp','on','Name','Multi');
rto=get_param(systems{1,1},'RuntimeObject')
if rto.OutputPort(1).Data == 1
    set_param(gcb,'BackgroundColor','red')
else
    set_param(gcb,'BackgroundColor','green')
end
```

When I press OK I get `Error: Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type`

When I use `keyboard` to debug I get this

```
K>> rto

rto =

    handle
```

It seems that it can't get the runtimeobject but when I do this while still in debug mode

```
rto=get_param(systems{1,1},'RuntimeObject');
```

while debugging I did get it

```
rto =

    Simulink.RunTimeBlock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't work.  Mask initialization happens during model initialization, at which point the block output may not even have a value.  Even if the code you show did execute, because mask initialization does not happen as the simulation is progressing, the color of your block would not change as the signal value changed.

The only way to do it (i.e. change the block color) is to have code that executes at every time step as the simulation progresses.  This is typically achieved using an S-Function.  Below is a very simple S-Function that will change the color of the Subsystem that it is in based on the value of the block's input signal.

[image]

The code in the S-Function is:

```
function msfcn_times_two(block)
% Level-2 MATLAB file S-Function for times two demo.
%   Copyright 1990-2009 The MathWorks, Inc.

setup(block);

%endfunction

function setup(block)

%% Register number of input and output ports
block.NumInputPorts  = 1;
block.NumOutputPorts = 1;

%% Setup functional port properties to dynamically
%% inherited.
block.SetPreCompInpPortInfoToDynamic;
block.SetPreCompOutPortInfoToDynamic;

%% Set block sample time to inherited
block.SampleTimes = [-1 0];

%% Set the block simStateCompliance to default (i.e., same as a built-in block)
block.SimStateCompliance = 'DefaultSimState';

%% Run accelerator on TLC
block.SetAccelRunOnTLC(true);

%% Register methods
block.RegBlockMethod('Outputs',                 @Output);

%endfunction

function Output(block)

if block.InputPort(1).Data < -0.5
    set_param(get_param(block.BlockHandle,'Parent'),'BackgroundColor','red')
elseif block.InputPort(1).Data < 0.5
    set_param(get_param(block.BlockHandle,'Parent'),'BackgroundColor','green')
else
    set_param(get_param(block.BlockHandle,'Parent'),'BackgroundColor','blue')
end
%endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you very much does there is a chance you can post a tlc file?

Comment: A tlc file would be pointless.  This is only something that can be done in simulation not externally to Simulink.

Comment: Well whIthout external bit only with mask it did worked in external mode and I saw the collor change using mask interface